# How to show the image of $h : (0, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(x) = 1/(x^2 + 8x)$ is equal to $(1/9, \infty)?$

Tags: functions

> How to show the image of $h : (0, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined
>   by $h(x) = 1/(x^2 + 8x)$ is equal to $(1/9, \infty)?$

Hi, I want to show that the image of $h : (0, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(x) = 1/(x^2 + 8x)$ is equal to $(1/9, \infty)$. Is there a quick way to do this? Maybe one can first prove that $h$ is injective on this domain, or that it's strictly decreasing. I don't know what the best way is.

Comment: The fast way is probably: $h(x)$ is strictly decreasing; $h(x)$ is continuous; $h(1) = \frac19$; and $h(x)$ tends to infinity as $x$ tends to zero. Each of these facts individually (assuming you have the mechanism of continuous functions set up) should be easy to prove.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{x}$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence $\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+8}$ is positive and decreasing on $\mathbb{R}^+$. 
It follows that the range of $h$ over $(0,1)$ is just $\left(\lim_{x\to 1^-}h(x),\lim_{x\to 0^+}h(x)\right)$.

Comment: Hi, could you please help me figure out how to prove the image using element-chasing technique? (e.g. choose an arbitrary $y$ from the image of $h$ and show that it is in the set $S = \{x \mid 1/9 < x < \infty\}$. Then do the same for the other direction so we can conlude the image equals $S$. I've been trying this for 2h, but cannot progress.

Answer (score 0):

Since for $x\in (0,1)$ we have $$0<x^2+8x<9\implies {1\over x^2+8x}>{1\over 9}$$

Since $h$ is continuous and $\displaystyle \lim _{x\to 0}h(x)=\infty$ and $\displaystyle \lim _{x\to 1}h(x)={1\over 9}$ we have the range $({1\over 9},\infty)$

Comment: Hi, could you please help me figure out how to prove the image using element-chasing technique? (e.g. choose an arbitrary $y$ from the image of $h$ and show that it is in the set $S = \{x \mid 1/9 < x < \infty\}$. Then do the same for the other direction so we can conlude the image equals $S$. I've been trying this for 2h, but cannot progress.